# How to log if a user removes a file from samba share

Tags: linux, samba, rhel6, samba4

I am working over the default Samba that comes with RHEL 6.x version. I am successful in sharing a samba share to my client users.

I have given each of them a set of credentials using which they have to connect to samba server and upload or download their files.

I am able to log the details like which is file is found in the samba share at a point of time in the file like samba.log.server but it is not so clear that which user uploaded which file or which user downloaded which file.

Moreover I could not be able to log the details like when a file is removed from the samba share by which user.

Could anyone help me in getting or tracking the above required details?

Comment: I looked into this a while back and it turns out there aren't really a lot of great options for you.  I ended up not being able to make any of them work and instead just yelled at my users to stop deleting files...that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Bert Neef for trying to answer the question. But with or without the above lines in the smb.conf file, I found the a line in the log file with the client's hostname as below:

```
reply_unlink : file1
```

when I deleted the file1. This is observed by doing many trails. So, this log entry in the samab log files may help us to know if the user deletes a file from the samba shares by connecting from the samba clients.

Answer (score 5):

It seems like the [vfs_full_audit](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/vfs_full_audit.8.html) feature should get you the required info:

Based on instructions found [here](https://moiristo.wordpress.com/2009/08/10/samba-logging-user-activity/) I think you should get it to work like this,
Add the following to smb.conf and restart Samba:

```
vfs objects = full_audit
full_audit:prefix = %u|%I|%m|%S
full_audit:success = unlink open 
full_audit:failure = none
full_audit:priority = NOTICE
```